# How to set Android push notification expiry time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to destroy android push notification massages after 5 minute. if user will not in network till 5 minutes that will automatically crashed/destroyed on google cloud itself and it will not be delivered at all.

Please suggest me how can i set expiry time in sent message over GCM?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which language you are using but there is a parameter "time_to_live" which is responsible for expiration of push notification.

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => 'registration id will go here',
        'data' => 'data will go here',
        'time_to_live' => 60
    );
```

let me know if any issue.